# Mvc application being redirected to login page when accessing third party dll function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, payment-gateway

I'm using a third party dll in my MVC3 application. When using the dll at localhost(my PC) it works great. But when I upload it to web server(shared hosting) I encounter a problem.
The application works fine when not using the functions in the dll. But when any function of the third party dll is called upon the page is redirected to the login page.

**NOTE:** I'm using Forms Authentication. 
I had set folder properties and set `<identity impersonate="true">` for the application to access files and folder in the web server.

Comment: what;s your meaning about third party dll? have you some payed libraries?

Comment: Yes I have payed libraries. I used them with normal asp.net and it worked fine in shared hosting. But Its not working with asp.net MVC.

Comment: So your App start and works normally, but in related pages to third party dlls? 2 reason get in mind: 1-Libraries are not compatible to MVC  2-Publishing has problems for third party dlls.

Comment: I think it might be something related to publishing. THIS IS WHAT I TRIED --> I tried BUILD DEPLOYMENT PACKAGE and deployed the contents to web server. But I didn't do it in my PC. Now I tried hosting it in my PC. Its showing the same problem. ---- It worked fine when running in visual studio so I don't think it would be because of MVC. Would it be????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your deployment package should contain necessary files for asp.net MVC. follow this steps in Visual Studio:

1. Right Click on your project
2. Select 'Add Deployable Dependencies ...'
3. Select Razor and MVC parameters
4. Build Deployment Package
5. Start Publishing

by doing this steps we'll ensure that MVC application works confidently even if host/server doesn't support MVC or Razor.

Answer (score 1):

I found that doing the following fixed the problem:

1. Expand the projects references.
2. Right click the reference in question.
3. Choose properties.
4. Change 'Copy Local' to 'True'.
5. Rebuild and publish project.
6. Test and do the same to any other required references if need be.